# Kernel copy windows and edit in linux

Tags: windows

I have an interesting question. If I copy the kernel of windows and tries to run in linux will it be possible to edit and create my own new one which is competiting to windows.?

Comment: So you want to somehow run the Windows kernel inside the Linux kernel. What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to run Windows as a guest system inside a virtual machine on a Linux host system?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is completely not possible.

The kernel is responsible for controlling everything your computer does, it has very specific interfaces and Windows and Linux are not compatible.

There are efforts to make Linux applications run on Windows such as the Cygwin project, and efforts to make Windows applications run on Linux, such as the Wine project. The other extreme is that some people are attempting to re-create windows, called ReactOS.

You could not copy the windows kernel since it is built from source code which only Microsoft has access to and to which only they have copyright for.

Your best bet is to learn programming and contribute to one of the projects mentioned above.

Comment: Not to mention it's illegal.